# Spring boot ClientHttpRequestInterceptor resend on 401

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, access-token, interceptor

So i have below scenario to implement using `Spring boot rest template` to consume a `REST-API` (involves token authentication mechanism). To perform test i've created simple mock REST API in spring boot. Here's the process,

From my API consumer app,

- sends a request using `rest-template` to consume a protected API, this API requires `Authorization: Bearer <token>` header to be present in request.
- if something is wrong with this token (missing header, invalid token), protected API returns `HTTP-Unauthorized (401)`.
- when this happens, consumer API should send another request to another protected API that returns a valid access token, this protected API requires `Authorization: Basic <token>` header to be present. New access token will be stored in a static field and it will be used in all other requests to authenticate.

This can be achieved by simply catching `401-HttpClientErrorException` in `RestTemplate` consumer methods `(postForObject)`, but the idea was to decouple it from `REST-API` consumer classes. To achieve it, i tried to use `ClientHttpRequestInterceptor`

Here's the code, that i tried so far.

**Interceptor class**

```
public class AuthRequestInterceptor implements ClientHttpRequestInterceptor {

private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AuthRequestInterceptor.class);
private static final String BASIC_AUTH_HEADER_PREFIX = "Basic ";
private static final String BEARER_AUTH_HEADER_PREFIX = "Bearer ";

//stores access token
private static String accessToken = null;

@Value("${app.mife.apiKey}")
private String apiKey;

@Autowired
private GenericResourceIntegration resourceIntegration; // contains methods of rest template

@Override
public ClientHttpResponse intercept(
        HttpRequest request,
        byte[] body,
        ClientHttpRequestExecution execution
) throws IOException {
    LOGGER.info("ReqOn|URI:[{}]{}, Headers|{}, Body|{}", request.getMethod(), request.getURI(), request.getHeaders(), new String(body));
    request.getHeaders().add(ACCEPT, APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
    request.getHeaders().add(CONTENT_TYPE, APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
    try {
        //URI is a token generate URI, request
        if (isBasicUri(request)) {
            request.getHeaders().remove(AUTHORIZATION);
            //sets BASIC auth header
            request.getHeaders().add(AUTHORIZATION, (BASIC_AUTH_HEADER_PREFIX + apiKey));
            ClientHttpResponse res = execution.execute(request, body);
            LOGGER.info("ClientResponse:[{}], status|{}", "BASIC", res.getStatusCode());
            return res;
        }

        //BEARER URI, protected API access
        ClientHttpResponse response = null;
        request.getHeaders().add(AUTHORIZATION, BEARER_AUTH_HEADER_PREFIX + getAccessToken());
        response = execution.execute(request, body);
        LOGGER.info("ClientResponse:[{}], status|{}", "BEARER", response.getStatusCode());

        if (unauthorized(response)) {
            LOGGER.info("GetToken Res|{}", response.getStatusCode());
            String newAccessToken = generateNewAccessCode();
            request.getHeaders().remove(AUTHORIZATION);
            request.getHeaders().add(AUTHORIZATION, (BEARER_AUTH_HEADER_PREFIX + newAccessToken));
            LOGGER.info("NewToken|{}", newAccessToken);
            return execution.execute(request, body);
        }

        if (isClientError(response) || isServerError(response)) {
            LOGGER.error("Error[Client]|statusCode|{}, body|{}", response.getStatusCode(), CommonUtills.streamToString(response.getBody()));
            throw new AccessException(response.getStatusText(),
                    ServiceMessage.error().code(90).payload(response.getRawStatusCode() + ":" + response.getStatusText()).build());
        }

        return response;
    } catch (IOException exception) {
        LOGGER.error("AccessError", exception);
        throw new AccessException("Internal service call error",
                ServiceMessage.error().code(90).payload("Internal service call error", exception.getMessage()).build()
        );
    } finally {
        LOGGER.info("ReqCompletedOn|{}", request.getURI());
    }
}

private String generateNewAccessCode() {
    Optional<String> accessToken = resourceIntegration.getAccessToken();
    setAccessToken(accessToken.get());
    return getAccessToken();
}

private static void setAccessToken(String token) {
    accessToken = token;
}

private static String getAccessToken() {
    return accessToken;
}

private boolean isClientError(ClientHttpResponse response) throws IOException {
    return (response.getRawStatusCode() / 100 == 4);
}

private boolean isServerError(ClientHttpResponse response) throws IOException {
    return (response.getRawStatusCode() / 100 == 5);
}

private boolean unauthorized(ClientHttpResponse response) throws IOException {
    return (response.getStatusCode().value() == HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.value());
}

private boolean isBasicUri(HttpRequest request) {
    return Objects.equals(request.getURI().getRawPath(), "/apicall/token");
}

private boolean isMifeRequest(HttpRequest request) {
    return request.getURI().toString().startsWith("https://api.examplexx.com/");
}
```

}

**Token generate method- In `resourceIntegration`**

```
public Optional<String> getAccessToken() {
    ResponseEntity<AccessTokenResponse> res = getRestTemplate().exchange(
            getAccessTokenGenUrl(),
            HttpMethod.POST,
            null,
            AccessTokenResponse.class
    );
    if (res.hasBody()) {
        LOGGER.info(res.getBody().toString());
        return Optional.of(res.getBody().getAccess_token());
    } else {
        return Optional.empty();
    }
}
```

**Another sample protected API call method**

```
public Optional<String> getMobileNumberState(String msisdn) {
    try {
        String jsonString = getRestTemplate().getForObject(
                getQueryMobileSimImeiDetailsUrl(),
                String.class,
                msisdn
        );
        ObjectNode node = new ObjectMapper().readValue(jsonString, ObjectNode.class);
        if (node.has("PRE_POST")) {
            return Optional.of(node.get("PRE_POST").asText());
        }
        LOGGER.debug(jsonString);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(RestApiConsumerService.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return Optional.empty();
}
```

**Problem**

Here's the log of mock API,

```
//first time no Bearer token, this returns 401 for API /simulate/unauthorized
accept:text/plain, application/json, application/*+json, */*
authorization:Bearer null
/simulate/unauthorized


//then it sends Basic request to get a token, this is the log
accept:application/json, application/*+json
authorization:Basic M3ZLYmZQbE1ERGhJZWRHVFNiTEd2Vlh3RThnYTp4NjJIa0QzakZUcmFkRkVOSEhpWHNkTFhsZllh
Generated Token:: 57f21374-1188-4c59-b5a7-370eac0a0aed
/apicall/token


//finally consumer API sends the previous request to access protected API and it contains newly generated token in bearer header
accept:text/plain, application/json, application/*+json, */*
authorization:Bearer 57f21374-1188-4c59-b5a7-370eac0a0aed
/simulate/unauthorized
```

The problem is even-though mock API log had the correct flow, consumer API does not get any response for third call, here's the log of it (unnecessary logs are omitted).

```
RequestInterceptor.intercept() - ReqOn|URI:[GET]http://localhost:8080/simulate/unauthorized?x=GlobGlob, Headers|{Accept=[text/plain, application/json, application/*+json, */*], Content-Length=[0]}, Body|
RequestInterceptor.intercept() - ClientResponse:[BEARER], status|401 UNAUTHORIZED

RequestInterceptor.intercept() - GetToken Res|401 UNAUTHORIZED
RequestInterceptor.intercept() - ReqOn|URI:[POST]http://localhost:8080/apicall/token?grant_type=client_credentials, Headers|{Accept=[application/json, application/*+json], Content-Length=[0]}, Body|
RequestInterceptor.intercept() - ClientResponse:[BASIC], status|200 OK
RequestInterceptor.intercept() - ReqCompletedOn|http://localhost:8080/apicall/token?grant_type=client_credentials

RestApiConsumerService.getAccessToken() - |access_token2163b0d4-8d00-4eba-92d0-7e0bb609b982,scopeam_application_scope default,token_typeBearer,expires_in34234|
RequestInterceptor.intercept() - NewToken|2163b0d4-8d00-4eba-92d0-7e0bb609b982
RequestInterceptor.intercept() - ReqCompletedOn|http://localhost:8080/simulate/unauthorized?x=GlobGlob
```

`http://localhost:8080/simulate/unauthorized` third time does not return any response, but mock API log says it hit the request. What did i do wrong ?, is it possible to achieve this task using this techniques ? or is there any other alternative way to do this ? any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

I have tried this:

Add an interceptor ClientHttpRequestInterceptor

```
    import java.io.IOException;

    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate;
    import org.springframework.http.HttpRequest;
    import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
    import org.springframework.http.client.ClientHttpRequestExecution;
    import org.springframework.http.client.ClientHttpRequestInterceptor;
    import org.springframework.http.client.ClientHttpResponse;
    import org.springframework.util.StringUtils;






    public class RequestResponseHandlerInterceptor implements ClientHttpRequestInterceptor {


        @Autowired
        private TokenService tokenService;

        @Autowired
        private RedisTemplate<String, String> redisTemplate;

        private static final String AUTHORIZATION = "Authorization";

        /**
         * This method will intercept every request and response and based on response status code if its 401 then will retry 
         * once
         */

        @Override
        public ClientHttpResponse intercept(HttpRequest request, byte[] body, ClientHttpRequestExecution execution) throws IOException {
            ClientHttpResponse response = execution.execute(request, body);
            if (HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED == response.getStatusCode()) {
                String accessToken = tokenService.getAccessToken();
                if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(accessToken)) {
                    request.getHeaders().remove(AUTHORIZATION);
                    request.getHeaders().add(AUTHORIZATION, accessToken);
//retry                    
response = execution.execute(request, body);
                }
            }
            return response;
        }

    }
```

Apart from this you need to override RestTemplate initialization as well.

```
@Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        restTemplate.setInterceptors(Collections.singletonList(new RequestResponseHandlerInterceptor()));
        return restTemplate;
    }
```

Comment: i'll try this too

Comment: A word of caution when using an interceptor in this way: calling `execution.execute()` a second time within the `intercept` method does not cause the new request to go down the full execution chain.  If you have other interceptors on this restTemplate (besides `RequestResponseHandlerInterceptor`), those interceptors have already been called and the second invocation of the request will not go through those.

Comment: @mattforsythe , care to elaborate a bit? Are there any alternatives? I’m stuck on a similar problem where I’m trying to use resilience4j-retry, and subsequent invocations are not triggering.

Comment: @simjohan, in this case, `RequestResponseHandlerInterceptor` may be one of several `ClientHttpRequestInterceptors` that get executed in order, one after the other.  Let's say the next one in line is a `LoggingInterceptor`.  If the code in `RequestResponseHandlerInterceptor`  ends up calling `execution.execute` twice, then the `LoggingInterceptor` would only be called on the first call to `execute`, not the second.  In the case of logging, this may not be a problem and may even be desirable, but that may not always be the case depending on what those other Interceptors are doing.